# Java swing: Calculate how many variables in text area

Tags: java, swing

This is my Text Area Code!! I need to calculate how many variables in this textArea code. Please help me. I am new to java.

```
 class Simple{  
 public static void main(String[] args){  
 int a=10;  
 float f=a;  
 System.out.println(a);  
 System.out.println(f);  
 }}
```

Comment: "_This is my Text Area Code_"  is it ? I can only see code that initializes two variable and prints their values.

Comment: @c0der: I think the OP wants to parse the Java code, and apply a lexer to determine the number of variables in his example.  To the OP, good luck.  You have many months of work ahead of you to develop a parser/lexer.

Comment: Do you want to get count of variables from text file? **or** Do you need to get count of variables from java file?